# Why do the docker componet faile to start in the i kuberenets deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, arm

> I run a pulumi deployment program to create a kubernetes cluster with a deployment on a Google Cloud Platfrom
> The Docker component in the deployment do not start.
> The Docker operating system: linux Architecture: arm64
> I get the error message
> "standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error""
> I think that the cause of this error message is that prossesor that I running on is not ARM . I am now running on e2-standard-2
> The  code that create a cluster looks like this

```
const cluster = new gcp.container.Cluster(name, {
    project: config.cloudProject,
    clusterAutoscaling: {enabled: true, resourceLimits:[ {resourceType: 'cpu', minimum:1 ,maximum:20 },
                                                         {resourceType: 'memory', minimum:1 ,maximum:64 }  
                                                       ]
                        },
    initialNodeCount: 1,
    minMasterVersion: engineVersion,
    nodeVersion: engineVersion,
    nodeConfig: {
        machineType: "e2-standard-2",
        oauthScopes: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
        ],
    },
   location: config.cloudLocation,
 
});
```

> The code  that creates a deployment looks like this

export const deployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("hello-world-deployment", {
spec: {
replicas: 1,
selector: { matchLabels: {app: "hello-world"} },
template: {
metadata: { labels: {app: "hello-world"},
namespace: nameSpaceName },
spec: {

```
       containers: [{ name: "hello-world-image",
                      image: "docker.io/steinko/gradle-ci-cd",
                      livenessProbe:{ httpGet:{path:'/actuator/health/liveness',
                                               port: 8080},
                                      initialDelaySeconds:5,
                                      timeoutSeconds: 1,
                                      periodSeconds: 10,
                                      failureThreshold: 3 
                                    } 
                    }],
    }
}enter code here
```

> How do I get the docker component up and running?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the image you pushed is only for ARM64 while the E2 machine type is x86_64. The two are not interchangable. You'll need to build an x86_64 version of the image either in addition or instead of the current one.

Comment: How do I make a x86_64 from my Mac Os Big Sure with Apple M1 ? How do I make a docker image that can run both on the MAc and in Google Cloud?

Comment: You need to use buildx last I checked, https://blog.jaimyn.dev/how-to-build-multi-architecture-docker-images-on-an-m1-mac/#tldr; looks like a decent summary.